# How do you get Safecracker to display category groups?

Tags: categories, safecracker

I am working on a new version of an existing magazine site. We are re-architecting the category structure, and I have set up a new category group.

We need to go through all existing articles and re-categorize them, and I am trying to build a tool for this purpose using Safecracker.

Unfortunately, this particular snippet doesn't work:

```
{category_menu category_group_id="3"}
    <select name="category[]" multiple="multiple">
            {select_options}
    </select>
{/category_menu}
```

… in fact it goes so far as to render all categories, in all groups, twice. (Using `group_id` doesn't change anything, nor does `cat_group`, both options I found through googling old ExpressionEngine forum posts.)

(I'm in ExpressionEngine 2.5.3.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done something similar with a group of checkboxes using the categories tag:

```
<label for="category-group-name">Category Group Name</label>
{categories group_id="3"}
  <option value="{category_id}"{selected}>{category_name}</option>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="{category_id}" {checked}=""> {category_name}</label>
{/categories}
```